# Old GDAL/OGR version with QGIS from ubuntugis in 14.10?

Tags: qgis, gdal

Installing QGIS 2.6 from ubuntugis installs an old GDAL/OGR (ogrinfo --version
GDAL 1.10.1, released 2013/08/26) - it should be 1.11 for support of the Open FileGDB connector in QGIS 2.6
So I don't have access on features in a FileGeodatabase.

How do I update to GDAL 1.11 without conflicts. The ppa for trusty (14.04) seems to contain the newer GDAL.

Comment: See this topic from the mailing list about outstanding issues for gdal 1.11: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.osgeo.ubuntu/953